# Can't connect to wifi with static IP on Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, wireless, server, internet

*Disclaimer: I've never worked with servers before, so this is new territory for me.*

I have gotten my server (no GUI) running with a static IP at my home, but I am now at college trying to connect it. The college wifi network is unprotected, but has one of those after-connection verification pages in the browser that verifies if the connected computer has a mac address registered in the system. I registered the mac address when a previous OS was installed.

Anyway, this is what I have for my /etc/network/interfaces file..

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlo1
iface wlo1 inet static
 address 10.36.133.145
 netmask 255.255.248.0
 network 10.0.0.0
 broadcast 10.36.135.255
 gateway 10.1.1.1
 wireless-essid ISU-CARDINAL
```

I have made sure the wlo1 interface is up with ifconfig wlo1 up, and verified its state with `ip addr`.

After doing `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, and making sure wlo1 is up, I am unable to `ping google.com` with the output `ping: unknown host google.com`. I am also unable to use `apt-get update` without getting errors.

If it makes a difference, I do not have NetworkManager installed.

Could someone help me figure out what I'm missing? I'd be happy to provide the output of any other commands that may help diagnose the issue.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have neglected to add DNS nameservers. I suggest you amend your `/etc/network/interfaces` to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlo1
iface wlo1 inet static
 address 10.36.133.145
 netmask 255.255.248.0
 gateway 10.1.1.1
 wireless-essid ISU-CARDINAL
 dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 10.1.1.1
```

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown wlo1 && sudo ifup wlo1
```

Check:

```
ping -c3 10.1.1.1
```

If you get ping returns, you are ready to access the verification page and proceed.

I assume that all the numbers above are verified correct, possibly from other connected devices or from the college.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, you want us to debug your WiFi connection. No problem, but do not expect it to work right now. Wireless errors can creep in all sort of places and we need to discard them out.

First, install the `bsdutils` package in your Ubuntu. This will provide `script` which you will need to capture your onscreen TTY output.

```
$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for youruser:
# script
Script started, file is typescript
# ifconfig
(some interesting output)
# route -n
(some interesting output, record the gateway corresponding to 0.0.0.0)
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
(some interesting output)
# ls -l /etc/resolconf/resolv.conf.d
(this will either give an error, 0 files, or a list of files. If you
get a list, show me their contents file by file)
# cat /etc/network/interfaces
(more)
# ls -l /etc/network/interfaces.d
(either says that no files in that directory or it enumerates them)
(in which case, I will also need their contents)
# ping -c 5 your_gateway_recorded_from_route_-n_command
# ping -c 5 gmail.com
# ^D
Script done, file is typescript
#
```

Last one is you press the `control key`, and while pressing it press the `D` key.

Now review the `typescript` file and make sure it does not contain any personal information, then post its contents here.

Comment: I don't think he is asking to troubleshoot the wireless at all. He has verified that he has a working wireless interface with `ifconfig`. Moreover, how is he going to install *bsdutils* without internet access? It is possible but you haven't explained how.